# simple functional equation differential equation

Tags: calculus

could you help to find the functional equation the function a(n)?
$$\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n a(k)}{k! (n-k)!}-a(n)=0$$

Comment: Why "differential" in the title?

Comment: $\large\left(-1\right)^{n}$ or
$\large\left(-1\right)^{k}\, ?$.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the equation you wrote? You have a $a(n)$ in the sum and then outside... And the $-1$ is also a bit strange... Where did you get this problem from if I can ask?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you meant $(-1)^k$.
$a(0)$ is arbitrary (the equations being linear).  The next few are
$\eqalign{
a \left( 1 \right) &=\frac{1}{2}\;a \left( 0 \right)\cr 
a \left( 2 \right) &=0\cr
a \left( 3 \right) &=-\frac{1}{14}\;a \left( 0 \right) \cr
a \left( 4 \right) &=-{\frac {5}{161}}\;a \left( 0 \right) \cr
a \left( 5 \right) &=-{\frac {303}{38962}}\;a \left( 0 \right) \cr
a \left( 6 \right) &=-{\frac {19298}{14006839}}\;a \left( 0 \right)\cr 
a \left( 7 \right) &=-{\frac {3734975}{20173850114}}\;a \left( 0
 \right) \cr
a \left( 8 \right) &=-{\frac {7822489317}{406694731373183}}\;a \left( 0
 \right) \cr
a \left( 9 \right) &=-{\frac {441186676819025}{295163581630864040446}}
\;a \left( 0 \right) \cr
a \left( 10 \right) &=-{\frac {267067254926198530996}{
3748812584504742296872415239}}\;a \left( 0 \right) \cr
a \left( 11 \right) &={\frac {35193289475757100448928429}{
27207382894903905785552567542641898}}\;a \left( 0 \right) \cr
a \left( 12 \right) &={\frac {4968536459619223597525881838395925}{
6516189955632109911312515475740484913197451}}\;a \left( 0 \right) \cr
a \left( 13 \right) &={\frac {
8628987176932410328414505053842570992875747}{
81152900793976831042522598158140820864614413594356502}}\;a \left( 0
 \right) \cr
a \left( 14 \right) &={\frac {
5364045407617140451997050325163713313358914776563410}{
505340801218633605848875558126318680984589307370102528169644707}}\;a
 \left( 0 \right) \cr
}$$

There doesn't seem to be any obvious pattern, and Maple's gfun package doesn't 
come up with anything.  I doubt that there's a closed-form solution.

Comment: Thanks great job i was calculate previously by hand some of above coefficient but Mr Robert could you explain the code to calculate with maple gfun i precciate yout help.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but assuming the $(-1)^n$ you could rewrite the formula with the binomial coefficients:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^na(k) \binom{n}{k}=a(n)(-1)^nn!
$$
Maybe it could help. I also calculated the first terms as @robertisrael but could not find any pattern quickly...